# Jquery works on one page and doesn't work on another with the same code/links

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, server

I'm trying to make my website work, but there seems to be some annoying issue. Everything works on local machine, but once I upload it to the server, only some pages have jquery plugins working while others don't. Even as I use the same exact links to jquery script files on both pages. I changed permissions back and forth but it didn't help. I don't even know why is it happening. 
And when it doesn't work, no jquery on this pages works at all.

Here is example a working page:
[working jquery page](http://www.mnabievart.com/info_mn/index.html)

And not working one:
[jquery doesn't work](http://www.mnabievart.com/info_mn/gallery_1.html)

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).liScroll is not a function`

Comment: without code its hard to get what is wrong..

Comment: And what does it mean, does it have something to do with a server?

Comment: There is one jqueryscroller.js missing on the second page

Comment: Missing `<script src="jqueryscroller.js"></script>` in second page.

Comment: You get an javascript error  at this line: `$("ul#ticker01").liScroll();` in gallery_1.htm

Comment: Ok I just added both jqueryscroller.js and removed second jquery link. It doesn't work anyway.

Comment: @LowPull  there is no `ul` element with `ticker01` ID, so better u remove this `$("ul#ticker01").liScroll();` line of code

Comment: Thank you! I don't know what it was doing there, I think I forgot about it after editing. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to include :

```
//include from here see if this works or remove your script and copy from this path it will work

<script src="http://www.gcmingati.net/wordpress/wp-content/lab/jquery/newsticker/jq-liscroll/jquery.li-scroller.1.0.js"></script>
```

instead include jquery twice :

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
```

Comment: I just removed it and put `<script src="jqueryscroller.js"></script>` back there. It doesn't work anyway.

Comment: include script from here :http://www.gcmingati.net/wordpress/wp-content/lab/jquery/newsticker/jq-liscroll/jquery.li-scroller.1.0.js

Comment: There is an  error in your jqueryscroller.js script, replace it with above link script.